# Difference between Laravel Collection methods has() and contains()

Tags: php, laravel, collections, contains

I'm having problems understanding the difference between the Laravel Collection methods `has()` and `contains()`.

> The contains() method takes a single value, a key-value pair of parameters or a callback function and returns a boolean value of the value is present in the collection or not.

So basically, it returns a boolean based on the existence of a value.

> has() - returns a boolean value if a key value is present in a collection or not.

And this also returns a boolean based on the existence of a value?

Somehow I don't get the difference of them.
I hope someone can explain it to me or share some useful links, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: You Can Read this in laravel Documentation:

Has: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-has
Contains: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-contains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello there i think the difference is that the has() methode search just the keys for example :

```
$collection = collect(['account_id' => 1, 'product' => 'Desk', 'amount' => 5]);

$collection->has('product');

// true

$collection->has(['product', 'amount']);

// true

$collection->has(['amount', 'price']);

// false
```

and The contains method() is used to determine if a given $key exists within the collection. Additionally, an optional $value can be specified that will be used to check if a given key/value pair exists within the collection.

Example 1 : in its most basic usage:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

// Create a new collection instance.
$collection = new Collection([
    'bear',
    'whale',
    'chicken',
    'tardigrade'
]);

// true
$collection->contains('bear');

// true
$collection->contains('tardigrade');

// false
$collection->contains('dog');
```

Example 2 : using the contains method to check if a given key/value pair exists in a collection that contains arrays as items:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

// Create a new collection instance.
$collection = new Collection([
    ['big'     => 'bear'],
    ['bigger'  => 'whale'],
    ['small'   => 'chicken'],
    ['smaller' => 'tardigrade']
]);

// true
$collection->contains('big', 'bear');

// true
$collection->contains('smaller', 'tardigrade');

// false
$collection->contains('smaller', 'paramecium');
```

Example 3 : used on collections of objects, using a hypothetical User class:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class User
{

    /**
     * A hypothetical user's first name.
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    public $firstName = '';

    /**
     * A hypothetical user's favorite number.
     * 
     * @var integer
     */
    public $favoriteNumber = 0;

    public function __construct($firstName, $favoriteNumber)
    {
        $this->firstName      = $firstName;
        $this->favoriteNumber = $favoriteNumber;
    }

}

// Create a new collection instance.
$collection = new Collection([
    new User('Jane', 7),
    new User('Sarah', 9),
    new User('Ben', 2)
]);

// true
$collection->contains('firstName', 'Jane');

// false
$collection->contains('firstName', 'Josh');

// false
$collection->contains('lastName', 'Jane');

// true
$collection->contains('favoriteNumber', 2);
```

good luck ;)

Answer (score 6):

`has` is for keys and `contains` for values.

```
$collection = collect(['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100]);

$collection->has('name'); // true
$collection->has('Desk'); // false

$collection->contains('name'); // false
$collection->contains('Desk'); // true
```

Answer (score 4):

Laravel documentation:

The has method determines if a given key exists in the collection
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-has

The contains method determines whether the collection contains a given item:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-contains

So the has method checks if a given key is in the collection, where as the contains method checks whether a given value is in the collection.